# c# question - is there a tool to identify where I should/can use a "using" statement to ensure resources are closed?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, using-statement

c# question - is there a tool to identify where I should/can use a "using" statement to ensure resources are closed? (to avoid memory leaks etc)

Including both the cases that:

a) there are resources not been closed and

b) syntax is using a try-catch-finally and identies this could be changed to a using

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it covers case b explicitly, but [Gendarme](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme) is a fine tool that will tell you [when you don't have a `using` statement](http://www.mono-project.com/Gendarme.Rules.Correctness#EnsureLocalDisposalRule) around disposable objects.

Comment: oh - can you use it on a non-mono project then?  i.e. VS2008 c# 3.5

Comment: @Greg - yup, Gendarme has worked great for me with .net 2.0 and 3.5 projects

Comment: @Greg: On Windows, Gendarme works nicely as a standalone tool, analyzing compiled .NET assemblies.  The standalone tool is at http://www.ohloh.net/projects/gendarme/download?package=Win32+installer

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the kind of tool that you're looking for, but [Code Rush](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Coding_Assistance/) will highlight your code when you have an object from a class that implements IDisposable and you're not diposing it.

Comment: I've got ReSharper at the moment - I don't think it has the support yet :(

Comment: I think ReSharper is way better than CodeRush. Anyway, why don't you give CodeRush Express a try? Maybe the express version can do what you want... http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/CodeRushX/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look if you can to enable code analysis in your project and turn on [`Microsoft.Reliability: Dispose objects before losing scope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182289(VS.80).aspx) rule

Comment: seems to require Team System?

Comment: sorry Greg, I can't to confirm right now, as I just have Team System here =/

Answer (score 0):

FxCop is a free tool from Microsoft that can do this.  It's also included in the "Team System" variants of Visual Studio 2005+